# What happens if a half-blood or muggle-born drinks unicorn blood?

Tags: harry-potter

What happens if a half-blood *or* muggle-born drinks unicorn blood?

Comment: Why should something different happen? Isn't it just a life extender with some downsides? I don't recall any mention that it depends on lineage?

Answer (score 12):

### The effects of drinking unicorn blood aren't dependent on blood status.

Unicorn blood will keep someone alive even if they're almost dead, though cursing them in the process. It's not dependent being a pure-blood - though it's unclear if it would work for a Muggle or only for wizards.

> “The blood of a unicorn will keep you alive, even if you are an inch from death, but at a terrible price. You have slain something pure and defenceless to save yourself and you will have but a half life, a cursed life, from the moment the blood touches your lips.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, Chapter 15 (The Forbidden Forest)*</sup></sub>

In fact, the Dark Lord, the only one who we see drinking unicorn blood, was a half-blood. It does strengthen him, exactly as it's supposed to.

> “Unicorn blood has strengthened me, these past weeks … you saw faithful Quirrell drinking it for me in the Forest …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

He uses it to strengthen himself after Quirrell as well, mixing it with venom from Nagini. Again, it strengthened him as expected, regardless of his blood status.

> “Voldemort’s red eyes fell upon the continually circling snake – ‘a potion concocted from unicorn blood, and the snake venom Nagini provided … I was soon returned to an almost human form, and strong enough to travel.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Comment: An excellent point about Voldemort being a half-blood and literally being the only example. Perhaps a better question would be "*what would happen if a full-blood drank unicorn blood"*...

Comment: I guess it’s worth pointing out that Quirrell was also drinking the blood.

Comment: @Adamant In the books, Quirrell's blood status is never mentioned, and if you believe Pottermore's *Power, Politics, and Pesky Poltergeists*, he's a half-blood just like the Dark Lord. In that case, we've *only* seen half-bloods drinking unicorn blood.